# Multitouch WPF on Windows7/8 on OSX doesn't work?

Tags: macos, windows-8-preview, parallels, wpf

Can I use Microsoft WPF(4) for multitouch when running Windows through Parallels on an OSX machine?

When I run Windows8 on my Mac the multitouch with touchpad works.
**But if I program my own WPF application multitouch doesn't work.**

Longer:
I have a Mac running OSX.  On it I have Parallels running a Windows8 virtual machine.  This Windows8 machine works nicely with multitouch by the Mac touch pad, swiping, zooming etc.  Then I create a WPF application with the templates that come with Visualstudio11 and get no multitouch.  I thought the WPF4 (4.5?) templates would be multitouch.  Are they and it is just the combination with my mac touchpad that doesn't work.
Or has someone got this to work?

Comment: Here is Parallel's info: http://kb.parallels.com/112443

Comment: The reportid to Parallels is 14484628.

Answer (score 1):

There's a difference between multitouch gestures provided by the trackpad driver and true multitouch support in windows. The Mac BootCamp driver does not support true multitouch on Windows (and niether do the synaptics touchpad/drivers).

One thing that you'll notice when you have true multitouch support is the 'Pen and Touch' applet running in your taskbar. This applet lets you manage multitouch settings.

[image: Pen and Touch]

I've used the [MultiTouchVista](http://multitouchvista.codeplex.com/) project and a 2nd mouse for testing multitouch on my development PC, but it crashes and bugs out quite regularly (sometimes the mouse pointer seems to be driven by a really active ghost).

Comment: Thankyou for the answer; Mac&Synaptics not being true Windows multitouch was valueable information.  I plan to contact Parallels and see if they have more info.

The fact remains though that Win8 and Mac touchpad seems to work nicely multitouch wise.  (but now with my own wpf apps)

Comment: You can put two fingers on the screen and see two inputs? Or is it that gestures like pinch zoom, scroll, rotate happen to work?

Comment: Gestures like pinch zoom, scroll and rotate happen to work.

Comment: Well no.  Now I don't think even that works.  Only swipe with two fingers.  In the maps application two fingers didn't pan but instead zoomed.  Maybe two fingers gets translated to mouse wheel and I just believed I was swiping.  Let's see what they'll come back with.

Comment: @LosManos - Yes, its gimmicky multi-touch. Like my answer stated, the Apple driver doesn't support it yet. Synaptic has a new standard that has WDM support. They are pushing it for Windows 8 systems. I'm starting to repeat myself, so I'll leave this question alone for now. Good luck.